# Migrating a giant production database without downtime

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-rds

We host a Rails app on AWS which uses mysql on the amazon-rds database.  We have a giant table in the database which we want to migrate, but it takes days to make the migration because of the millions of rows.  Specifically we're moving a `VARCHAR` to a `TEXT` column

How do I migrate this large production database without users experiencing downtime?

One idea I've heard is to setup a copy of the database, and make the migration there and switching it to be the main database when that's done.  However I'm not sure how this would take account of user data entered while the migration is ongoing.

**Update:** This may be relevant: [amazon-rds offers read replicas](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) and [Multi-AZ deployments](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/multi-az/) which seem like they might be made for this type of thing.  First time doing this, though, so would welcome guidance on any method whether it be this or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible with the hosting options you are using, but I would tackle the problem this way:

1. Copy the data to the new server (and record the binary log position on the old database server)
2. Turn on replication from the old server to the new server (and wait for it to catch up)
3. Reconfigure the Rails application to point to the new server

Read only mode is another potential option if a "write downtime" is more acceptable than a "full downtime" (depends on the application obviously).